# How to get back the information that the Matlab keyboard might have acquired(including passwords,etc)? Should I change them?

Tags: keyboard

When I switch into the Matlab keyboard it warns me that the entry methods might retain every information I type,including passwords,credit numbers,etc. I've already used the keyboard so I'd like to know which information has it retained, whether it's already shared it and erase it if posible.

Comment: To be fair, this is a general warning for all keyboard/text input apps due to its nature, *including the default keyboard app*. The question is still valid and can be applicable to any keyboard apps though.

Comment: Thanks, that's reassuring